# LibTorch: There's no way to put a model on the CUDA device that will process a tensor already on the CUDA device

Tags: c++, torch, libtorch

I cannot put, and keep the model on the CUDA device. I cannot send a tensor that is already on CUDA through a model without getting the "found at least two devices, cpu and cuda" error.
Did I miss some simple way of putting the model on the CUDA device in LibTorch? I cannot find it or figure it out.

The full, reproducible example is below, but the lines in question are quite simple as show below...
I have a tensor that is on CUDA I want to send it though a model. This causes an error

```
auto the_tensor = torch::rand({42, 427}).to(device);
std::cout << net.forward(the_tensor).to(device);  

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::Error'
what():  Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and 
cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_addmm)
```

If I do NOT put the tensor on CUDA I can run the tensor and the model both on CUDA like so

```
auto the_tensor = torch::rand({42, 427});
std::cout << net.forward(the_tensor).to(device);
```

I can also send the tensor back to the CPU and this also does NOT create an error. But, I have a large script with a lot of tensors that will already be on the CUDA device I DO NOT want to be sending the tensors from CUDA back to the CPU and then back to the CUDA device. This is why I call it a bug. How do I put the model on the CUDA device and keep it there other then putting .to(device) on the end of the model only when it is being called with forward `net.forward(tensor)`

```
auto the_tensor = torch::rand({42, 427}).to(device);
std::cout << net.forward(the_tensor.to(torch::kCPU)).to(device);
```

I have tried permanently putting the model on the device but nothing I try works.

```
net.to(device);
net->to(device);
Critic_Net().to(device);
```

I've tried many variations like these above to put the model on the CUDA device and keep it on the CUDA device but nothing works but to put the model on the CUDA device with `net.forward(the_tensor).to(device);`

The full, reproducible example.

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
using namespace torch::indexing;

torch::Device device(torch::kCUDA);

struct Critic_Net : torch::nn::Module {
    torch::Tensor next_state_batch__sampled_action;
    public:
    Critic_Net() {
        lin1 = torch::nn::Linear(427, 42);
        lin2 = torch::nn::Linear(42, 286);
        lin3 = torch::nn::Linear(286, 1);
    }
    torch::Tensor forward(torch::Tensor next_state_batch__sampled_action) {
        auto h = next_state_batch__sampled_action;
        h = torch::relu(lin1->forward(h));
        h = torch::tanh(lin2->forward(h));
        h = lin3->forward(h);
        return torch::nan_to_num(h);
    }
    torch::nn::Linear lin1{nullptr}, lin2{nullptr}, lin3{nullptr};
};

auto net = Critic_Net();


int main() {
    net.to(device);
    auto the_tensor = torch::rand({42, 427}).to(device);
    
    std::cout << net.forward(the_tensor).to(device);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are moving your model to gpu with the `to` function, libtorch does not move anything because you have not registered anything as parameters/buffers/modules. Hence when you call the forward method, incompatible devices are found and an error is raised. Here is how to register your submodules (see [doc](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_frontend.html#module-ownership))

```
struct Critic_Net : torch::nn::Module {
public:
    Critic_Net() {
        lin1 = register_module("lin1", torch::nn::Linear(427, 42));
        lin2 = register_module("lin1", torch::nn::Linear(42, 286));
        lin3 = register_module("lin1", torch::nn::Linear(286, 1));
    }
    torch::Tensor forward(torch::Tensor next_state_batch__sampled_action) {
         // unchanged 
    }
    torch::nn::Linear lin1{nullptr}, lin2{nullptr}, lin3{nullptr};
};
```

Note : in addition to `register_module` you have access to `register_parameter` and `register_buffer` which take tensors instead of modules. The difference is that the "parameters" are trainable tensors while "buffers" will not be trainable (they are useful if you want to keep a moving average of your inputs for example).